# For any series that diverges, does there exist a sequence that converges to 0 yet the product diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$. Does there exists a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 0$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n = \infty$? I am able to prove this for the case when $a_n$ diverges to infinity, but other than that, I am not sure what to do and don't have a sense of whether this should be true or false.

Comment: Do you have $a_{n+1}\geq a_n\geq 0$? In such a case, you can take $b_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1}}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}$. Anyway, I believe this was already asked on this site.

Comment: @Nameless It has to work for each $a_n$

Comment: You are not free to choose $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$, you are free to choose only $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$.

Comment: Ah okay, my fault.

Comment: Let $b_n = 1$ for all $n\leq N_1$ where $N_1$ is the smallest number satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{N_1} 1 \cdot a_n > 1$. Then let $b_n=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $N_1 < n \leq N_2$ where $N_2$ is the smallest number satisfying $\sum_{n=N_1+1}^{N_2} \frac{1}{2} \cdot a_n > 1$. Then let $b_n = \frac{1}{3}$ for all $N_2 < n \leq N_3$ ... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take an increasing sequence $N(m)$ such that $\sum_{n=N(m-1)}^{k} a_n \ge 1$ for $k \ge N(m)$, and define $b_n$ in terms of the greatest $m$ such that $n \ge N(m)$.